# Can't install VS2015 Pro - Installer thinks 2015 Enterprise is already installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This image pretty much sums up my problem:

[image: Can't install visual studio]

I don't have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 installed. I *did* have a prerelease version installed - which I have since uninstalled.

Things I've tried that didn't help:

- `vs_enterprise.exe /Uninstall /Force`
- Re-installing the Enterprise RC and uninstalling it.
- Installing the release version of 2015 Enterprise (tells me there's a preview version I need to uninstall)
- Manually deleting all references to Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 14.0 from the registry
- Pulling out all of my hair

VS 2015 does not exist in my "Programs and Features" and the files don't exist on my disk.

I also have VS 2013 installed which works fine, but I'd like to upgrade to the latest version and currently that is proving quite difficult.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check registry for this key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\12.0
then choose the installed version then  edition you want to remove..example:
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\15.0\enterprise
and remove it!
Edit:
This is the path that used to detect VS according to Microsoft official website
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164659.aspx

Comment: Thanks...but I don't have that key. I have no `vs` under `SOFTARE\Microsoft\DevDiv`. :(

Comment: I'm sorry but that's the path that visual studio installation checks when running.. and I didn't upgrade to 2015 so  I guess they've changed the path..I've two solutions:<br>
1-use a total uninstaller.. like "my uninstaller" which checks for left registry keys..
2- use a registry tracer (like regmonitor) and run the installation.. it will show you which registry path it's checking

Comment: So according to the website.. I guess that you didn't find it because you have a 64 version.. so please check Wow6432Node

Comment: The key was here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\`, that link gave the answer :). Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.. enjoy the professional version ;)